# Electron - Is there an event that is activated while exe or dmg being extracted

Tags: electron

In my electron app I need to get a token from server with the application download by the users.

The token is per user, and I suppose to support a lot of users (so I cant rebuild the application for each user).

I thought about the solution of changing the exe / dmgg file name to include also the token, than to extract the file name and to get from the the token.

1. is there a way to get file name while exe / dmg are being extracted to their folder.
2. is there an option to push a file, update json file etc to also include this token, without rebuilding the exe and without breaking the signing certificate.

Thank you

Comment: What is wrong with getting this token on app's first launch and then persist it in a config file?

Comment: what do you mean with app's first launch - asking user to login? we want to avoid it.

Comment: When the user runs the app for the first time I mean

Comment: yes, but do you mean that the user will have to type himself the user name?

Comment: We don’t know how how your users system work. You just said you needed to store a token somewhere: store it in a JSON file somewhere on your user computer with `app.getPath` https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname the first time you run the app

Comment: If your token needs to be generated on EXE download, then just Zip the EXE with a token.txt file server-side before giving it to the user, and find it on app’s first launch with the usual js variables to know in which directory you are

Comment: I cant change the exe - since I have signing on it. and I dont want to rebuild the exe for each user

Comment: You do not have to rebuild the EXE, you just have to Zip the Exe with a token in a separated file